# Ember-cli and app structure

Tags: ember.js

I am playing with ember-ci and trying to figure out where I should put the files. Most tutorials that I have found, put them in one file and it just works.

This is my [application](https://github.com/johndel/ember-cli-test/tree/master/app). My problem is that the templates/application.hbs doesn't render the views/index.html and the views/about/html which according to what I've read, it should render it on the outlet of the application template.

Should I put these files somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through your application. Here are a couple of mistakes I noticed.

1. You are putting html files in the `views` folder.
   The template files should be put inside the `templates` folder with the extension `hbs`.
2. In you templates, you are specifying 'data-template-name'. But that is not necessary. Just put whatever html you want to display in that hbs file. The name of this file is the relevant part. Ember-cli uses a custom resolver. It resolves controllers, templates, view... etc based on the name of the file. You may want to go the project site to see the naming conventions. Its a bit different than the naming conventions in ember site.

Okay now here are the steps I did to get you site working.

1. Moved the files `index.html` and `about.html` from the `views` folder to the `templates folder. I changed the extension of both these files to`.hbs`.
2. Removed the script tags inside the 2 templates mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you! After many tries I managed to find the index.hbs and about.hbs but I didn't know it was due to the resolver.